# Showing Route Between 2 Places Using Google Map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps, ios7, ios6, ios6-maps

I want to draw a route between two points in **Google Map** using **Google Map iOS SDK**.

Here I have two text fields `From` and `To`. I implemented Google auto-complete API for that 2 text fields. I am getting **Latitude** and **Longitude** of the two places. Now I want to draw a route between those two points.

I searched for this one but couldn't find a solution.  How can I implement this?